# Depth value problem

Tags: ros, kinect, rosbag, depth

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I use rosbag to record the information from a kinect camera, then I export the depth image from the bag file, but the image pixel value seems wrong with just a few values like 0,1,2. I don't know why. Does anybody can help me?

Regards

Wei

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9341/depth-value-problem/) by [Bruce](https://answers.ros.org/users/224/bruce/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2011-03-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
the output depth image is a floatingpoint image containing the depth values in meters. So, what format did you use to save them and read them back? Did you maybe use gray scale images instead?

-Suat

---

Originally posted by [Suat Gedikli](https://answers.ros.org/users/275/suat-gedikli/) with karma: 91 on 2011-03-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1